# Running python scripts on local host

Tags: python, python-2.7, web

I am a newbie to python . I am not bad with python programming , but never started using it with web. So I figured it out that python same as php can work on localhost via xampp .But as said It is displaying the python script contents. How can I exactly interpret code in apache(using xampp) an show it in browser. If there isn't any way please give me an alternative to use python on localhost.

Please do correct me if I am wrong anywhere because as I said I am new to python programming and cs world.

Comment: Unfortunately, python does not work the same way php does. So, simply putting it on a server will not work. You need to create the server server (using wsgi), and if you want o host it on an apache server then you need to configure mod_wsgi. It isn't as simple as putting a file into the root directory or your server.

Comment: Does modifying mod_wsgi resolve my issue??

Comment: Where are you placing the python scripts?  Should be in the cgi directory.

Comment: Yeah...But a server error came up

Comment: @GamesBrainiac  Can you explain in detail about modifying mod_wsgi file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simpliest way for a noobie to run a webserver is probably to use flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/

Just try to get the example on the homepage running first. It has a built in webserver. Then when you're more familiar and you want to deploy it behind apache, you can follow this: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/

Comment: Thank you...I really need it urgent so I thought it would be easy if it worked with xampp..